# Children props are not visible in parent component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

In child component, I set the props as following:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user : state.App.get('user'),
    foo: 'ok'
  }
}
```

But when I read `this.props.children` in `render` method of parent component, `foo` is not there. Anyone knows why?

I realized that I can't see the child state from a parent in my project. Am I missing something?

I'm also using Redux in this app. Whats wrong? What's the proper way of doing something like `this.props.children.foo` in parent Component?

Comment: Is `user` available?

Comment: no, not in this.props.children. there are things in it, but seems to be built-in attributes from the core of React (`_store`, `props`, `_owner`, and in `children.props` there are `route`, `history`, `params`)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be referencing `this.props.children.foo` to get foo. Once you've connected your component to `mapStateToProps`, you should be able to reference it just from `this.props.foo`

`this.props.children` will retrieve all the elements enclosed within an opening and closing tag of React component.

There is a CodePen example on the React documentation page that illustrates this: 
http://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ozqNOV?editors=0010

```
function WelcomeDialog() {
    return (
        <FancyBorder color="blue">
            /*everything between these two blocks*/
            <h1 className="Dialog-title">
                Welcome
            </h1>
            <p className="Dialog-message">
                Thank you for visiting our spacecraft!
            </p>
            /*is what is sent to FancyBorder as this.props.children*/
        </FancyBorder>
    );
}
```

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html